# Noon Hour Observation

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with a number of rows as follows:

```
+---------------------+------+
| utc                 | temp |
+---------------------+------+
| 2011-01-30 00:00:14 |   -3 |
| 2011-01-30 00:40:06 |   -4 |
| 2011-01-30 01:00:15 |   -4 |
| 2011-01-30 01:20:14 |   -4 |
| 2011-01-30 02:00:12 |   -4 |
| 2011-01-30 02:20:18 |   -4 |
| 2011-01-30 03:00:16 |   -4 |
|         ...         |  ... |
```

`utc` is of type `datetime`, and `temp` is of type `int`.

For each day, I would like to find the `temp` value closest to that day's noon hour. Possibly resulting in a table which looks like this:

```
+---------------------+------+
| utc                 | temp |
+---------------------+------+
| 2011-01-30 12:01:14 |   -3 |
| 2011-01-31 11:58:36 |   -4 |
| 2011-02-01 12:00:15 |   -5 |
| 2011-02-02 12:03:49 |   -7 |
| 2011-02-03 02:00:12 |   -8 |
|         ...         |  ... |
```

Finding this for a single day is easy enough:

```
SELECT utc, temp FROM table WHERE DATE(utc)='2011-01-30' ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,utc,DATE_ADD(DATE(utc),INTERVAL 12 HOUR))) LIMIT 1;
```

But somehow doing this for every day at the same time is proving a good deal more challenging.

(Note, that there may be more values than just `temp` in the table.)

Comment: have you considered a stored procedure? Might be overkill, but it is a simple way to filter out the data

Comment: maybe a double query?? select all temp from the result of the query you post. Like a SELECTCEPTION

Comment: Yes, @Sebastien, a double query would work, though the exact formulation is not coming to mind.

Comment: @Richard Have you try removing the WHERE clause of your current query? only this part `WHERE DATE(utc)='2011-01-30'`

Comment: Aside, but why noon UTC?  That could be the middle of the night depending on location.

Comment: @MattJohnson, fair enough, but it's easy enough to adjust the location by adding the appropriate number of hours. Maybe I should have simplified the question to midnight UTC. In this case, the location is well-defined, so this method is fine.

Comment: Sure.  As long as you realize noon UTC isn't noon everywhere. :)  The approach is fine.

Comment: Absolutely, @MattJohnson :-) Thanks for keeping a watchful eye.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a stored procedure:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure get_temps(d0 date, d1 date)
begin
    declare d date;
    declare done tinyint default 0;
    declare cur_dates cursor for
        select distinct date(utc) as date 
        from `table`
        where date(utc) between d0 and d1;
    declare continue handler for not found
        set done = 1;
    -- Create a table to store the data
    create table if not exists tbl_temp_data (
        utc datetime,
        temp int
    );

    open cur_dates;
    temp_filter: while done=0 do
        fetch cur_dates into d;
        if done = 0 then
            insert into tbl_temp_data
            SELECT 
                utc, temp 
            FROM 
                `table` 
            WHERE 
                DATE(utc)=d
            ORDER BY 
                ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,utc,DATE_ADD(DATE(utc),INTERVAL 12 HOUR))) 
            LIMIT 1;

        end if;
    end while;
end $$
delimiter ;
```